# easiest way to implement indoor navigation for home / company building

Tags: navigation, wifi

I was wondering what the easiest way (re-using existing software, libraries) is to create a indoor navigation app based on Wifi Access Point locations. I could use [Google indoor maps](http://support.google.com/gmm/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1685872&topic=1685871&ctx=topic) but it's probably not wise to upload your home floor plans and make them available on the net.
Are there any alternative solutions at hand? So far I could only find [Redpin.org](http://redpin.org/).

Technical constraints:

- navigation based on AP location
- should work on every smartphone
- maybe even browser based?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a new app in Android, the best way is to use the WiFi based indoor navigation using the wifi triangulation method in addition to useing sensors like the gyroscope, accelerometer etc.
Try googling to find the WiFi triangulation methods. In android it is easy to find the WiFi details.